# AIR: Error #2032 when I run program from CD\DVD

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

I have a problem with AIR in my project .

I want to read an xml file stored program next swf . My xml file has entries (path) to other files.

To read the file I using URLLoader

```
...
var urlRequest : URLRequest = new URLRequest ( url ) ;
var _loadXML : URLLoader = new URLLoader ();
_loadXML.load ( urlRequest ) ;
...
```

Export release as signed application with captive runtime.

I run the exe from the hard drive - the program works.
When I burned files on CD / DVD drive and try to run the program exe from cd/dvd shows the error "# 2032 Streaming " .

AIR does not see my files in cd / dvd. Why?

Comment: You should know that your xml file should be included in the install package and when you load it you should use a relative path.

Comment: A little remark : may be it's a typing error but you can not do : `var URLRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest()` because you can not use a AS3 class name as a var name.

Comment: Sorry, my bug in copy code. Var name is different of class name :)

Comment: ... And what about my first comment ?

Comment: I tried include XML. Xml file is visible, but other files are in cd-rom next application not found. Now I resolve my problem as follows: Create temp dir and copy files from AplicationDirectrory to temp directory. Use files from temp file. When I using File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("myfile.jpg"), application not response. For this moment this resolve is ok for me, but this resolve no works in windows Xp :/

Comment: Could you show us how do you load your xml file, are you using an absolute or relative path ? And, how did you install your AIR application in the CD (steps to do that) ?